# laravel alternate php version path

Tags: laravel

During Laravel installation in shell I get error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 148
```

As I understand the reason is wrong PHP version. 5.6.4+ is requred, but default version on my server is 5.4.16.
However I have alternate versions of php on server, PHP7 for example.

Is there any way to tell laravel installer path to this alternate version /opt/php70/bin/php?
Or may be there is some other solution to solve this issue?

P.S. Changing default version is not a solution. Have other sites running on server

**UPDATE**
Thanks for everyones advices, finaly it worked for me like this.
Setting in shell PHP alias:

```
alias php="/opt/php70/bin/php"
```

And installation with composer

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel
```

Comment: How are you doing the install? With composer or the `laravel` command?

Comment: I install with: laravel new blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the installer uses the PHP version that's in your path, but you can specify which one you want to use by including it in front of the command. I.e.

```
/opt/php70/bin/php /path/to/composer/vendor/bin/laravel new blog
```

Or with just composer

```
/opt/php70/bin/php composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a laravel specific way to do this once you've setup the project but you can use a PHP version manager like https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew

Follow the install steps in the readme, install a version of PHP with PHPbrew and then create a .phpbrewrc file in the home directory of your laravel project, for example with the command

echo 'phpbrew use 7.1.6' > ~/path/to/project/.phpbrewrc

Not that installing PHPBrew will override your normal PHP install so you have to use PHPBrew with EVERY project.